# What is the fill order of Numpy fromfile for a 2-D ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, custom-data-type

I'm trying to read a structured binary file using the `numpy.fromfile()` function. In my case, I have a `numpy.dtype()` which is used to define a user defined data type to use with `np.fromfile()`.
I will reproduce the relevant part of the data structure here( for the full structure is rather long):

```
('RawData', np.int32, (2, BlockSize))
```

this will read `BlockSize*2` number of int32s into the field `RawData`, will produce a `2xBlockSize` matrix. This is where I am having trouble because I want to replicate the behavior of Matlab's [fread()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) function, in which the matric is filled in [column order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#btp1twt-1-sizeA). As for NumPy's `fromfile()`, this isn't mentioned (at least I couldn't find it).

It doesn't matter NumPy's `fromfile()` should work like Matlab's `fread()`, but I have to know how NumPy's `fromfile()` works to code accordingly.

Now, the question is, what is the fill order of a 2-D array in the NumPy `fromfile()` function when using a custom data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromfile` and `tofile` read/write flat, 1d, arrays:

```
In [204]: x = np.arange(1,11).astype('int32')                                                          
In [205]: x.tofile('data615')
```

`fromfile` returns a 1d array:

```
In [206]: np.fromfile('data615',np.int32)                                                              
Out[206]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int32)
```

`x.reshape(2,5).tofile(...)` would save the same thing.  `tofile` does not save `dtype` or `shape` information.

reshaped to 2d, the default order is 'C':

```
In [207]: np.fromfile('data615',np.int32).reshape(2,5)                                                 
Out[207]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

but it can be changed to MATLAB like:

```
In [208]: np.fromfile('data615',np.int32).reshape(2,5, order='F')                                      
Out[208]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

The underlying `databuffer` is the same, just a 1d array of bytes.

### edit

The file could be read as a 2 integer structure:

```
In [249]: np.fromfile('data615','i4,i4')                                                               
Out[249]: 
array([(1,  2), (3,  4), (5,  6), (7,  8), (9, 10)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [250]: _['f0']                                                                                      
Out[250]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int32)
```

It's still a 1d array, but with numbers grouped by 2s.

## Converting to complex:

```
In [252]: xx = np.fromfile('data615','i4,i4')                                                          
In [253]: xx['f0']+1j*xx['f1']                                                                         
Out[253]: array([1. +2.j, 3. +4.j, 5. +6.j, 7. +8.j, 9.+10.j])
In [254]: _.dtype                                                                                      
Out[254]: dtype('complex128')
```

If the data had been saved as floats, we could load them as complex directly:

```
In [255]: x.astype(np.float32).tofile('data615f')                                                      
In [257]: xx = np.fromfile('data615f',np.complex64)                                                    
In [258]: xx                                                                                           
Out[258]: array([1. +2.j, 3. +4.j, 5. +6.j, 7. +8.j, 9.+10.j], dtype=complex64)
```

Another way to get the complex from the integer sequence:

```
In [261]: np.fromfile('data615', np.int32).reshape(5,2)                                                
Out[261]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]], dtype=int32)
In [262]: xx = np.fromfile('data615', np.int32).reshape(5,2)                                           
In [263]: xx[:,0]+1j*xx[:,1]                                                                           
Out[263]: array([1. +2.j, 3. +4.j, 5. +6.j, 7. +8.j, 9.+10.j])
```

Comment: So, what you're suggesting is that I should read the data as a 1-D array and then reshape it where I can specify the order I need, right? I haven't thought of that before.

Comment: I assume the raw data is just a flat sequence of 4byte integers.  And 2d or other block structure is imposed on it during loading, or after.  Other than just reading the numbers as 1d sequence, we could read them in groups of 2.  See my edit.

Comment: It's a sequence of complex numbers stored on the binary file, each pair is a complex number (a+ib). What I have already done is read the whole block as a 1d array and select every other element starting from 0 as the real part of the complex numbers, and the rest as the imaginary part, to construct a complex 1d array like this: `cmplx=RawData[0::2]+1j*RawData[1::2]`. Now, I think your edited part would be much better, I'll see how it works out.

Comment: I've added some ideas for complex values.

Comment: thanks mate. Is it possible to reserve some space in the structured array that is read from the file so that I can add data later on. I need to do some processing on this complex data and would like to add that back to the structured array to keep the program tidy, otherwise I would have to have a separate list to store that or append it to the structured array I already have. Since appending to a numpy array isn't efficient, I am trying to avoid that. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: If you know the size beforehand you can allocate a numpy.empty with the target capacity, but you have to deal with storing the "correct" size yourself, then. Appending to an array is also possible, but that might involve some copying of the data. But I'd try the latter, and only try the former if it leads to performance issues. "premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming"

Comment: `np.zeros((N,), dtype=dt)` works for a compound dtype just as well as a simple one.  However assigning values is a bit tricky.  Data either has to be a list of tuples, or be assigned by field.   Since both fields are the same (int or float), I think the 2d array approaches are better - either (2,N order F) or (N,2).

Answer (score 1):

By default, when creating a new 2-d array, NumPy will use "C" ordering, which is [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).  That is the opposite of the order used by Matlab.

For example, if `BlockSize` is 4, and the raw data is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

then the 2 x 4 array will be

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

With Matlab and that same raw data, the 2 x 4 array would be

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6],
 [1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: I have seen the order being specified with the reshape() function, is it possible to specify the order with fromfile() function?